# How to get last edited time of a comment through FQL/Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

We have built a system that get all posts and comments from our FB page.

The updated_time on stream has the following description "The time of the last comment on this post".

We use this to get notified when new comments are posted on posts.
When this date changes, we call API to get the new comments.

However, if a comment gets edited. There seems to be no way to be notified?

The "updated_time" on the post, is not changed.
Nor is the there any time on the [comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment) that gossips about any changes made. The only date column on comment we have is the time column, but that does not change if comment is edited.

I believe that Facebook should add a "updated_time" on comments as well and also let the edited time reflect on the "updated_time" on posts.

But for know, does anyone have any solution?