# Facebook updated time for edited comments

Tags: facebook-fql

Now that Facebook provides the ability to edit comments, I was looking for a way to grab comments that were newly edited.  I can search the comments table for comments to a particular post and include time in the where clause, but time is the created time and not updated time.  Is there any time field that gets updated, either in the comment table or elsewhere, when a comment gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a question on this with no answer:

[How to get last edited time of a comment through FQL/Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520802/how-to-get-last-edited-time-of-a-comment-through-fql-graph)

It looks like Facebook hasn't updated their fql API for this.  I'm assuming it would be a "foreign key/primary key" linked table with edited info columns.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment